# Filter Visual Studio Debug Output for specific messages only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, maui

I found only a handful of questions on this topic, and the [closest match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1767899/5438626) has no accepted answer. My code is using `Debug.WriteLine` with the aim of producing real time messages without the need to open a log file or add a break in the program, which I *could* do in my custom trace listener:

```
class TraceListenerMauiEx : TraceListener
{
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (message.Contains("240308.A"))
        {
            Filtered.AppendLine($"{message}");
        }
        TraceListenerEvent?.Invoke(this, new TraceListenerEventArgs(MessageType.Write, message: message));
    }
    public event EventHandler<TraceListenerEventArgs> TraceListenerEvent;
    public class TraceListenerEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public TraceListenerEventArgs(MessageType messageType, string message)
        {
            MessageType = messageType;
            Message = message;
        }

        public MessageType MessageType { get; }
        public string Message { get; }
    }
    public StringBuilder Filtered { get; } = new StringBuilder();
}
```

On that note, if I were debugging the `WinUI` build I could pop up my own non modal window to monitor these filtered messages, but I'm debugging the Android version and there's just not enough screen real estate to do this in a useful way.

This might give a sense of the volume of information that is not useful as compared to the yellow-highlighted messages that I care about. But there's such an obvious case for being able to do this that I have to think that the functionality must be "in there" somewhere that I don't know about.

[image: debug trace]

---

*I use this trace listener across the board in MAUI and Winforms code and so am tagging it as such to cast a wider .NET* for possible solutions.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT with some additional searching I managed to find your Xamarin post on [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/211415/removing-unnecessary-messages-in-output-window-whe) suggesting an **environment.txt** file at the root level containing `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=error` and this does seem to do what I want once the app gets going (which is the important thing). Is that information already somewhere on SO and I didn't find it? If not, is it something you'd be willing to summarize as an answer on this thread?

Comment: The original is on SO at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760798/xamarin-android-turn-off-mono-logs . Note that it doesn't affect VS's output directly - it filters the lower-level logging at the mono level, before VS gets involved. Obviously, it only addresses mono-based runtimes and isn't a direct answer to this question.